# Is there a way to save highlighted part of a dataframe to an excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare two dataframes (headers same in both of them)and highlighted the data which is not similar in both the frames .

Now I want to print those rows which are highlighted  to an excel sheet keeping the headers. And I'm unable to do that

[image: Example output image]

Comment: Select the rows you want via `.loc`, use the `.to_excel` method

Comment: How do I select these particular rows .Is there a code snippet or something for me to work on. Forgive me I'm pretty new to this . @PaulH

Comment: Please copy and paste your dataframe here, and what you tried

Comment: I posted a picture for reference in the question @U9-Forward

Comment: @MurtuzaAkhtari [NO, pictures are useless](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: There are *dozens* of questions on stack overflow about selecting rows out of data frames. Do none of them answer that for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for differences by comparing each element of each corresponding row (here I use the unique `id` column to find corresponding rows). If there is a difference you can append it to a new dataframe. Finally save the new dataframe to excel format.

```
df_differnt_rows = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','B','C'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[3,2,3]], columns=['id','B','C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,"different",2],[3,2,3]], columns=['id','B','C'])

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
  compare_row = df2.loc[df2['id'] == row['id']].iloc[0]
  if all(row == compare_row):
      continue
  df_differnt_rows = df_differnt_rows.append(compare_row)
```

This produces another df that has all the rows that are different between df1 and df2.

```
print(df_differnt_rows)

    id  B           C
1   2   different   2
```

Save using `.to_excel()` method:

```
df_differnt_rows.to_excel('df_differnt_rows.xlsx')
```

Check out [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable) (i.e. patternfill) if you want to highlight cells in the excel file.

Comment: you (generally) don't need to loop with data frames.

Comment: @PaulH I updated the answer to remove loop :)

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 :- Select the row you want and store it in a new frame, say df
( selecting rows in python can be done using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-extracting-rows-using-loc))
.

Step 2 :- 
Use this :-

`df.to_excel (r'C:\Users\Desktop\selected_dataframe.xlsx')`

`#Don't forget to add '.xlsx' at the end of the path`

Comment: How do I select the row i want?

Comment: Check the edited one

Comment: I actually want to select the rows which I have highlighted . And I'm unable to find a way to access rows on the basis of that

Comment: Did you read the link I've attached. you need to do something similar like that, probably and use a little tweak to be able to do so

Comment: yes I did . will work on it . and will let you know about the result